# jQuery and CSS3 Simple Tooltip not working on the scrolled page

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

I'm using [jQuery and CSS3 Simple Tooltip](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/681/jQuery-and-CSS3-Simple-Tooltip.html) and it works fine but only as long as the content fits the viewport. After the page must be scrolled it gets offset, and at the bottom of page doesn't show at all.

Here's a snippet:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //Tooltips
    $("body").on("mouseover", ".tip_trigger", function(){
  //$(".wrapper").on("mouseover",".tip_trigger", function(){
      var tip = $(this).find('.tip');
      tip.show(); //Show tooltip
    });
 
 $("body").on("mouseout", ".tip_trigger", function() {
      var tip = $(this).find('.tip');
   tip.hide(); //Hide tooltip
 });
 
    $("body").on("mousemove", ".tip_trigger", function(e) {
      var tip = $(this).find('.tip');
   var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coodrinates
      var mousey = e.pageY + 20; //Get Y coordinates
      var tipWidth = tip.width(); //Find width of tooltip
      var tipHeight = tip.height(); //Find height of tooltip
      
      //Distance of element from the right edge of viewport
      var tipVisX = $(window).width() - (mousex + tipWidth);
      //Distance of element from the bottom of viewport
      var tipVisY = $(window).height() - (mousey + tipHeight);
        
      if ( tipVisX < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the X coordinate of viewport
        mousex = e.pageX - tipWidth - 20;
      } if ( tipVisY < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the Y coordinate of viewport
        mousey = e.pageY - tipHeight - 20;
      } 
      tip.css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
});
 });
```

```css
   .tip {
    color: #fff;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);/*#1d1d1d;*/
    display:none; /*--Hides by default--*/
    padding:2px 10px;
    position:fixed;
 z-index:1000;
  }
.tip:after {
        position: absolute;
         top: -10px;
        left: 0;
        width: 0;
        border-top: 10px solid  transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        border-left: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        content: " ";
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="tip_trigger"><span class="tip">Some text displayed in tooltip</span>Link</a>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br /><a class="tip_trigger"><span class="tip">Text in second tip, still in viewport but after scrolling it gets damaged</span>Link 2 </a>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<a class="tip_trigger"><span class="tip">Some other text displayed in tooltip</span>Link 3</a>
```

Can anyone help with that?

Comment: Works fine. I could see the tooptip for the last span : http://jsfiddle.net/xrg59705/1/

Comment: your `.tip` has position fixed, it will gone wild. try position `absolute` and give your `a` tag position `relative`.

Comment: Hm.. thanks for tip, this works for this simple snippet, but on a more complex page where class="tip" can be added not only to a link but to div, img or even table it behaves even worse and is offset far away...